# Combining calendar and array in Delphi 7

Tags: arrays, delphi, calendar

I'm working on a project in Delphi 7. I'm trying to let a user select a day by clicking on a day on the TCalendar component, the corresponding day has to be found in an array and the event should be displayed. Any ideas how to do let the user select a day on the calendar and use this as a variable?

Comment: Are you just creating new accounts in order to ask [duplicate questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25834535)? If so, that's highly discouraged here; you should be editing your prior question instead to get it reopened. (It's very coincidental that two new users would both be using the same antiquated Delphi sample component `TCalendar` at the same time trying to do the same thing, unless it's a homework assignment given to your class.)

Answer (score 2):

> Any ideas how to do let the user select a day on the calendar and use this as a variable?

Read the calendar date with the [`CalendarDate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Samples.Calendar.TCalendar.CalendarDate) property. Or the `Day`, `Month` and `Year` properties. Exactly how you then look up your events depends on how your events are stored.